# Matplotlib Visualisation always crashes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to visualize a an array with matplotlib. I'm working in Visual Studio Code with Python 3. This is my Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

a = numpy.zeros( [3,2] )
print(a)

a[0,0] = 1 
a[0,1] = 0
a[1,0] = 2
a[1,1] = 0
a[2,0] = 3
a[2,1] = 0

print(a)



plt.imshow(a, interpolation="nearest")
```

When i run the code the array is getting printed on the console, but the seconds after the window with the graph is popping up it immediately crashes. I also dont get an error.
However with this code a window is popping up with the graph:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

X = [590,540,740,130,810,300,320,230,470,620,770,250]
Y = [32,36,39,52,61,72,77,75,68,57,48,48]

plt.scatter(X,Y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: the main difference i see between the two examples is that the one that works includes `plt.show()`, and the one that doesn't work does not include `plt.show()`

Comment: PaulH = King  -- it's working now